# How to pass a prop from one component to another when using react router link

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I want to pass the prop productId from the home component to the main component.

How can i pass some initial state when i navigate to a new component

**home component**

```
let productId = "123" // get from query string

return (
       <Button className="startButton"
                            variant="contained"
                            color="primary"
                            component={Link} to="/main"
                            fullWidth>
                            Start
                        </Button>
)
```

**main component**

```
export class Main extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            productId: "",
        }
  }

}
```

Then in my main component i can set the state of that productId.

**router**

```
const Router = () => {

    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
            <Route exact path="/main" component={Main} />
        </Switch>
    )
}

export default Router;
```

I am using the following library
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start

Update:
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/basic-components/route-rendering-props

You can see here the example passes in some extra property `someVariable` i want to be able to do that.

Comment: How your components are connected to each other?

Comment: I don't think i understand the question. I have a router file where i declare all the urls and what component is should render based on the exact path. In my home component i am then using the react router link to navigate to the main component based on the url `component={Link} to="/main"` does that help?

Comment: If they are not connected in any way then `redux` is the right way to pass data between components - https://redux.js.org/

Comment: Im already using redux

Comment: As you are already using `redux`, you can maintain `productId` in reducer, dispatch the action to update `productId` from home component as and when your query gets executed, connect your main component to redux store, now you can have updated value in main component when you navigate to the same.

Comment: Ye i didint think i would need redux for something as simple as this, especially when there is an example of something similar here. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/basic-components/route-rendering-props

Just my setup is slightly different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like wrapperLink component which is given below. In the given example I have given constant state value instead give the value dynamically

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Tabs from "@material-ui/core/Tabs";
import Tab from "@material-ui/core/Tab";
import { Switch, Route, Link, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const wrapperLink = (state, path) =>
  React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
    <Link
      innerRef={ref}
      to={{
        pathname: path,
        state: {
          ...state
        }
      }}
      {...props}
    />
  ));

const state = {
  title: "sample"
};

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <Route
          path="/"
          render={({ location }) => (
            <Fragment>
              <Tabs value={location.pathname}>
                <Tab label="Item One" component={Link} to="/" />
                <Tab label="Item Two" component={wrapperLink(state, "/tab2")} />
                <Tab
                  label="Item Three"
                  href="#basic-tabs"
                  component={Link}
                  to="/tab3"
                />
              </Tabs>
              <Switch>
                <Route
                  path="/tab2"
                  render={props => <div>{props.location.state.title}</div>}
                />
                <Route path="/tab3" render={() => <div>Tab 3</div>} />
                <Route path="/" render={() => <div>Tab 1</div>} />
              </Switch>
            </Fragment>
          )}
        />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Here is working example in codesandbox [click here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-uis-tabs-integration-with-react-router-4-ji0xl)

Comment: This is what i was looking for, but it did not work for my example my main component does not have the state productid. Do i need to assign a default state of productid="" in main compoennt

Comment: Ah i found it in {props.location.state.title}

Answer (score -1):

If I clearly understand you don't need to pass, since they are already available in properties match Object.

```
export class Main extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const {productId} = props.match.params; 
        this.state = {productId}
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not available there its empty. I am going from home component which receives a query param and moving to the main component.

Comment: This is not something the OP has asked.